# Dynamics CRM Outlook Client Modifications - can it be done?

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-4

I'm working on customizing the Dynamics 4.0 CRM interface to remove things our company doesn't use.  For the web interface I'm modifying the SiteMap xml file, which makes changes to the left navigation bar in the Website interface.  These changes do not roll over to the Outlook client.  For example, I want to get rid of the Resource Center.  I remove it from the XML file and import it to change the web interface.  Volia! The Resource Center is gone.  These changes are not reflected in the Outlook client - the Resource Center is gone from the web, but remains in the Outlook client.

Is there any way to do this?  The Outlook client is cluttered with a lot of stuff we don't use, and I'd like to make whole sections go away.

Answer (score 2):

The Outlook client does generally use the same Sitemap you see in the online client, but it is extremely fussy about it. If there is the slightest thing it doesn't like (and that will even apply to items with different IDs but the same *display* title), it will revert to the default Sitemap without telling you why.

When facing such problems, start with a single item by commenting out everything else, and then gradually add stuff until Outlook stops using the customized Sitemap, then try to find out what's wrong with the item you added last.